# GetMaterialApp.router clear all route Get.rootDelegate.navigatorKey.currentState! .popUntil((route) => route.isFirst) in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-getx

After Login or Registration clear all previous screen and go to first screen.

This command not working:-

1. `Get.rootDelegate.offAndToNamed(RoutesName.routeHome);`
2. `Get.rootDelegate.popRoute();`
3. `Get.rootDelegate.popHistory();`
4. `Get.offNamedUntil(RoutesName.routeHome, (Route<dynamic> route) => route.isFirst);`
5. `Get.offAll(RoutesName.routeHome);`

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you would like to have please? did you try to use some middleware like in https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/example_nav2/lib/app/routes/app_pages.dart ? best regards,